# How to set gap size constant in between the cards in CSS?

Tags: html, css

In the first screenshot this is the full screen so the gap between the cards are fine:-

[image]

In the second screenshot when I decrease my window size then the gap automatically changes so its not constant:-

[image]

My css code is :

```
.cards {
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /*max-width: 1000px;*/
  display: grid;
  /*grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr); Recorrected below*/
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(262px, 1fr));
  gap: 10px;
  row-gap: 30px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

how can I make the gap constant so that whether i reduce the window size or not the gap should remain constant and not reduce then nd then.
kindly pls help me with this i have just started to program.

Comment: apply same css to all window size use media queries

Answer (score 0):

remove `row-gap` and just use `gap: 10px` (or whatever value you prefer)

**EDIT**
Here's an example of using grid-gap.

```css
.cards {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 30px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fill, 100px);
  width: 100%;
}

.cards div {
  background: coral;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cards">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
</div>
```

Comment: still its same if I remove row-gap and use only gap

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the row-gap property. The gap set with a fixed value is enough to achieve what you are looking for.

Your items will flow taking a minimum of 262px and fitting as much per row as possible, separated 10px horizontally and vertically.

And maybe that margin: 0 auto is not needed.